# Placing an input-field in a label, changing bgcolor on focus

Tags: html, css

So what I'm trying to do, is to put an input-field over a label and change the background-color of the input-field on focus. So that the bgColor covers the text of the label.

Here is what it looks like:

```
<div class="d-faq-field">
  <label class="i-faq-lastname-label" for="i-faq-lastname">Nachname</label>
  <input id="i-faq-lastname" type="text" name="lastname">
</div>
```

I've put both input field and label in a div so that everythings responsive and the div's can float beside each other.

Also, have a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utd5N/). There is a div on the top where it already works but I cannot seem to reconstruct it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I well understood try simply

```
input:focus {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;    
}
```

so, when the input is focused it will cover the label. Anyway you will see the label again when the input loses its focus.

Probably you could obtain the right behaviour simply using the `placeholder` attribute

Comment: Oh my, now that's ridiculous. I've been trying to fix this for 3 hours. That's exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Placeholder wouldn't pass the WCAG 2.0 since its contrast wouldn't be high enough and the textcolor for placeholders isn't changeable in every browser yet.

Comment: @NoReply looking at the most-voted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css it seems it is possible to change the colour on almost all current browser.

Comment: I know, unfortunately the project has to support IE7+ though.

Comment: well, placeholder is not supported until IE10, so whatever polyfill you decide to use for that attribute you will be able to also set the right colour

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood, but why not use the placeholder attribute?

```
<textarea id="i-question2" required="required" type="search" name="question" placeholder="Gib hier deine Frage ein"></textarea>
```

Comment: See my comment for Fabrizio Calderan's answer.